# visual studio changes chmod of file and I want to stop this happening

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2019 to change cpp files that are saved in linux server. The problem is after I change and save files  that has chmod of 644, Visual Studio automatically changes files chmod 644 to 755 without any notice.

I want to stop this happning. Is there any way stop VS to change chmod?

Comment: How do you copy the files there? Using a post-build-step or using a remote build?

Comment: I don't copy. I have access permision and accessed with ftp address. I just open folder and file with visual studio diretly by accessing folder address. I can also access with putty if I want to.

Comment: You are directly opening a folder on a network share with Visual Studio? That sounds like a bad idea. You should use a version control system instead, together with automatic deployment. The probable reason why you have this problem is that VS is a Windows application, and file permissions on Windows work very differently than on linux. The chmod is probably not from VS, but from your FTP/Network software.